# (Android - Kotlin) - Embed Open Street Map (OSM) using an OSM URL (with Relation ID)

Tags: android, kotlin, openstreetmap

I'm building a simple Geography app where I would like to use Open Street Map to display each country on a map.
(I don't wish to use Google Maps, because it's not 100% free and I don't wish to set a Google Cloud account)

I want to use an URL (from OSM) to locate and display a given country:
example URL: https://www.openstreetmap.org/relation/53292

Here I want to use the Relation ID : ( 53292 )  as the starting data to display the right location on the map. But I couldn't find the right method to so. I'm pretty that this is possible. Does anyone have an idea on how to do it? Thanks

My code so far:

```
countryURL = "https://www.openstreetmap.org/relation/53292"

    binding.mapView.setUseDataConnection(true)
    binding.mapView.setTileSource(TileSourceFactory.MAPNIK)
    binding.mapView.setMultiTouchControls(true)


    val mapController : IMapController
    mapController = binding.mapView.getController()
    mapController.zoomTo(14, 1)

   // TODO: Get that countryURL's relation ID and use it to set the map view to that 
   //relation ID (i.e. country).
```

I found this **binding.mapView.setExpectedCenter()** , but it's seems to be using coordinates instead of the relation ID, maybe there is a way to convert that relation ID to coordinates programatically?

Comment: You can use the OverPass API from OsmBonusPack to develop an Android app https://github.com/MKergall/osmbonuspack/wiki/OverpassAPIProvider.

Answer (score 0):

In order to get the coordinates (or better: the bounding box) of a relation you have to look at its elements. For all ways that *belong* to this relation obtain all nodes. For all these nodes *and* all nodes that are directly part of the relation get all coordinates. Iterate through them and store the minimum and maximum latitude and longitude. Done, you have your bounding box.